# C# - How can I correct string case in HashSet<string> within a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I have a variable like below:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

I want to make sure the values in the HashSet are unique using `StringComparer.Ordinal`. What would be the syntax for that? Thanks.

Comment: Well at some point you'll be creating the hash set that you're using as the value for an entry, right? So pass `StringComparer.Ordinal` into the `HashSet<string>` constructor. The fact that you're using it as the value in a dictionary entry is irrelevant.

Comment: Values in a .Net HashSet are guaranteed unique by definition. If you add a duplicate to a hashset, nothing new happens and the `Add()` method just returns 'false'.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I think the OP is interested in ensuring that it's unique under that specific comparison (as opposed to, for example, a case-insensitive comparer).

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you initialize a new key, the value should be passed an explicit parameter like this:

```
dict["some key"] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```